# unexpected output from a function returning a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I have a function `stuff()` which returns a string to be printed from `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* stuff(char* thing) {
        return ("this and %s", thing);
}

int main() {
        char* thing = "that";
        printf("%s\n", stuff(thing));
        return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting

> this and that

to be printed when the program is run, but instead I see:

> that

Is someone able to walk me through what the program is actually doing, and more importantly, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this line:'return ("this and %s", thing);' is the root of the problem.  In C, this is two expressions, separated by a comma, NOT a method to concatenate two strings.  in a comma delimited list of expressions, the expressions are evaluated left to right,  only the right most expression is used (the other expressions are evaluated) so all that is being returned is a char * to the contents of 'thing'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using an expression with the *comma operator* as the return value of your function.

The comma operator evaluates both operands (the expressions on either side of the comma), and the *result* of the expression is the result of evaluating the second expression: the expression on the right hand side of the comma. in your case, the second expression is the result, and hence is returned as the return value of your function.

So the result of the return statement in your function is equivalent to:

```
return thing;
```

Which is why the result of your function is the string `"that"`.

You seem to be expecting some kind of `printf` style string formatting from this expression:

```
("this and %s", thing);
```

but it won't work like this: it's just an expression using the comma operator.

In C, concatenating strings isn't this easy. Look into the standard string `strcat` family of functions (see documentation for `strncat` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/)), or one of the `sprintf` family of functions (documentation for `snprintf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)).

Comment: The Linux man pages project ([`strncat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncat.3.html), [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)) is much better than the cplusplus.com reference for the C library, because C and C++ are different languages, and the Linux man pages are much more comprehensive, actively maintained, and not Linux specific at all. Especially see the "Conforming to" and "Notes" sections on each man page. Finally, if GNU extensions are available, I'd recommend [`asnprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

[pbq2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32062172/) explains very well why you get the expected output you get due to the comma operator. So I'd like to address your expectations, it looks like you are expecting some sort of string formatting expression to occur like you would see in other languages such as python. Unfortunately no such behavior happens in C. You need to use something like [`snprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to do what you want here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* stuff(const char* thing) {
    char* ret = malloc(100);//make sure you deallocate this later!
    snprintf(ret, 100, "this and %s", thing);
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    const char* thing = "that";
    printf("%s\n", stuff(thing));
    return 0;
}
```

Also you might note that I have changed the original code to use `const char*` instead. This is because string literals should not be modified.

Comment: ops, forgot to pass the returned value from stuff() to free(), infact didn't even keep the returned value so it could be passed to free()

Comment: Also you should avoid using `char *` to point at non-mutable strings, and protect against buffer overflow.

Comment: @user3629249, this code is merely a proof of concept to highlight something for the original poster without changing the function parameters. (This is just an example of a Wittgenstein's ladder.) The proper way to deal with it would be to malloc the space in main then pass that pointer over to the `stuff` function, in any case ownership of the memory should not be the responsibility of the `stuff` function.